# Adding Tree Header for Button in Odoo

Tags: button, treeview, odoo, odoo-14

I have added icons in tree view to perform some actions and i want to show header / label to these buttons. For example, I have two icons on tree view and its header title is empty. So I want to add a single heading for these icons which will be "Action" for eg. for all the records like other fields heading.

I have tried a link for this and exactly I want the same in my case but didn't worked for me. Here [is the link](https://www.confianzit.com/cit-blog/tree-view-button-avoiding-the-blank-space-in-the-tree-header-for-corresponding-button/).

[image]

Here is the screenshot of what I am getting while implementing the code. It is displaying the string in the icon itself but not in the tree header.

Comment: May I know the version of your odoo?

Comment: it's odoo14 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node tag attribute will be set to `button_group`, the `string` and `class` attributes will be available in the child attributes.

Try to change the `_renderHeaderCell` to:

```js
_renderHeaderCell: function (node) {
    const $th = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    if (node.tag === 'button_group' && node.children && node.children[0].attrs.class === "custom_identifier"){
        $th.text(node.children[0].attrs.string)
        .attr('tabindex', -1);
    }
    return $th;
},
```

Comment: Hello kenly, thanks for your response. I have tried your code but not working for me like it is adding the string to the icon itself, but not to the tree header. i have edited my post with screenshot of what i am getting after implementing the code.

Comment: Is it like i can't use any other class with "custom_identifier"?

Comment: I used the example above, a button with one class. If you use multiple classes my example above will not work. Instead of using `===`,  try to use `includes`: `node.children[0].attrs.class.includes("custom_identifier")`

Comment: but after trying "includes" also, i am getting string in icon, although, it appears in header but string is also visible inside the icon(as shown in screenshot). how can i remove that string from icon?

Comment: I have solved this one by using title in $th.text(node.children[0].attrs.title) instead of $th.text(node.children[0].attrs.string) and applied it to xml also with title tag like title="Action" . Thanks kenly for your help. it worked for me.